# How works Jasmine YouTube Client for ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, youtube

As you know, there is no way to play YouTube video on iOS using `MPMoviePlayerController` (except the case where you extracting a direct url before passing the url into MPMoviePlayerController which is prohibited by Google). It is possible with `UIWebView` though.

But how does `Jasmine` app works? I did not find any trace of UIWebView in the application. Is there a legal way to play youtube with MPMoviePlayerController that I can use?